# :last-child of nested list using shadow dom

Tags: css, css-selectors, web-component, shadow-dom

To style the last element of a nested list...

```
<div>
    <div>
        <div>1</div>
        <div>2</div>
    </div>

    <div>
        <div>1</div>
        <div>2</div> <!-- style this -->
    </div>
</div>
```

...we can use this selector:

```
div>div:last-of-type>div:last-of-type
```

But if these `<div>` were web components using shadow dom - how does one style this last element (without JS)?

A global selector wouldn't work because it'd have no influence on the children. And a child itself wouldn't know if it's *really* the last child because it can't look "outside" itself.

Any ideas?

Comment: Your use of divs is confusing. Where does each component's shadow tree start, and end? Are these all nested shadow trees or one giant shadow tree? If it's the latter, :last-of-type will certainly work.

Answer (score 0):

You are not saying where does really your shadow starts. But I guess that the only problem would be when it starts mid-level.

In this case, setting a css variable in this should work:

I am crossing the shadow boundary using the --mycolor property

```css
.element:last-child {
  --mycolor: red;
}

.inner:last-child {
    background-color: var(--mycolor);
}
```

```html
<div>
    <div class="element">
        <div class="inner">1</div>
        <div class="inner">2</div>
    </div>

    <div class="element"> <!-- shadow starts here -->
        <div class="inner">1</div>
        <div class="inner">2</div> <!-- style this -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi @vals, shadow starts at the first div (imagine all the divs being the same 
 Web Component).